# Javascript code to show and destroy bootstrap popover not performing as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a function `createPopover()` that is being used to create a popover over an element as follows:

```
function createPopover(destination, content){
    var popoverTemplate = ['<div class="timePickerWrapper popover">',
            '<div class="arrow"></div>',
            '<div class="popover-content login-popover">',
            '</div>',
            '</div>'].join('');
    destination.popover({
        template: popoverTemplate,
        content: content,
        html: true,
        placement:'top',
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
    destination.popover('show');
}
```

It is called as follows:

```
createPopover($('.drop-time-text'), 'Please select a drop off time');
```

I've also written a destroy popover function that destroys all popovers on the page present or not

```
function destroyPopover(destination){
    $('.styled-select-car').popover('destroy');
    $('.pick-date-text').popover('destroy');
    $('.pick-time-text').popover('destroy');
    $('.drop-date-text').popover('destroy');
    $('.drop-time-text').popover('destroy');
}
```

These are being used in a basic validation process as follows:

```
if(pickUpDate == ''){
    destroyPopover(); //All popovers removed before creating a new one
    createPopover($('.pick-date-text'), 'Please select a pick up date');
    return false;
}
```

where `pickUpDate = $('.pick-date-text').val()`.

While debugging the code proceeds in the expected manner but in the UI, the popover appears on first click but flickers and dies on the second click of the validation button. I'm not quite sure as to why this is happening.

Comment: I checked your code and bootstrap API, looks fine to me. Maybe some kind of bug... No answer, sorry

Comment: @JeremyThille I think it's an issue with event propagation inside `destroyPopover` because the moment I removed the call from inside the if statement, it's working as intended but of course the popovers wont be removed before another one is created.

Comment: Could also just be an issue of timing; adding a brief delay to destination.popover() in createPopover() would test if that's the case.